# Collapsable tree structure from JSON endpoint - webcomponent

Tags: javascript, json, nested, web-component

I'm trying to make a web-component that output the activityId and description of all the activities and nested children. I've added my full JS code over here: https://codepen.io/dennisperremans/pen/qBQRQwZ

And my JSON file: http://jsonblob.com/1123161096512094208

This is the part were I'm rendering the activity tree:

```
 renderTree(data) {
      let tree = '';
      for (const item of data) {
        tree += `<li>${item.description} (ID: ${item.activityId})`;
        if (item.childActivityId && item.childActivityId.length > 0) {
          const nestedChildren = this.renderTree(item.childActivityId);
          tree += `<ul>${nestedChildren}</ul>`;
        }
        tree += '</li>';
      }
      return tree;
    }
```

The code render the parents, but not the children. The output of the children is **undefined (ID: undefined)**

The nested children can go 4 levels deep.

Comment: your fetch doesn't work in the codepen

Comment: That's because of CORS issue. I temporary bypass thisissue with a chrome-extension

Comment: it seems the url timeouts, no cors or other error.. so I'd guess the server might be blocking some clients..

Comment: Hmm, it's possible that it's not accessible from outside the company network.

Comment: The Web Component here is nothing but a big container. So you are building an application, not components. Tell tale sign is the loop where you attach eventListeners on DOM, and complete JSON structure, instead of only the relevant parts. Make every displayed activity item a Web Component with a single clickhandler. The more components you build the better you can test, debug and extend functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the data is not assigned for some reason.

(*edit*: looks like the endpoint times out, so check that it's available, or use another endpoint)

It works when hardcoded (here's a few).

However, your toggler doesn't seem to work: when clicked, it shows children, but hides parent.

It's fixed with adding `event.stopPropagation();` in the click handler:

```
  item.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    
    event.stopPropagation();
```

```js
class ActivityIndex extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
        this.data = {
  "result": [
    {
      "activityId": 39978,
      "activityCode": "01",
      "description": "Crop and animal production, hunting and related service activities",
      "parentActivityId": null,
      "parentActivityDescription": null,
      "customAcertaActivity": false,
      "isTradeActivity": false,
      "requirementActivity": [],
      "startDate": "2008-01-01",
      "endDate": null,
      "matchesQuery": "",
      "version": "Versie 2008",
      "versionMapping": [],
      "comment": "",
      "hasChildren": true,
      "childActivityId": [
        {
          "activityId": 39988,
          "activityCode": "011",
          "description": "Teelt van eenjarige gewassen",
          "parentActivityId": "39978",
          "parentActivityDescription": "Teelt van gewassen, veeteelt, jacht en diensten in verband met deze activiteiten",
          "customAcertaActivity": false,
          "isTradeActivity": false,
          "requirementActivity": [],
          "startDate": "2008-01-01",
          "endDate": null,
          "matchesQuery": "",
          "version": "Versie 2008",
          "versionMapping": [],
          "comment": "",
          "hasChildren": true,
          "childActivityId": [
            {
              "activityId": 40099,
              "activityCode": "0111",
              "description": "Teelt van granen (m.u.v. rijst), peulgewassen en oliehoudende zaden",
              "parentActivityId": "39988",
              "parentActivityDescription": "Teelt van eenjarige gewassen",
              "customAcertaActivity": false,
              "isTradeActivity": false,
              "requirementActivity": [],
              "startDate": "2008-01-01",
              "endDate": null,
              "matchesQuery": "",
              "version": "Versie 2008",
              "versionMapping": [],
              "comment": "",
              "hasChildren": true,
              "childActivityId": [
                {
                  "activityId": 40424,
                  "activityCode": "01110",
                  "description": "Teelt van granen (m.u.v. rijst), peulgewassen en oliehoudende zaden (Mogelijk burgerlijke activiteit)",
                  "parentActivityId": "40099",
                  "parentActivityDescription": "Teelt van granen (m.u.v. rijst), peulgewassen en oliehoudende zaden",
                  "customAcertaActivity": false,
                  "isTradeActivity": true,
                  "requirementActivity": [],
                  "startDate": "2008-01-01",
                  "endDate": null,
                  "matchesQuery": "",
                  "version": "Versie 2008",
                  "versionMapping": [],
                  "comment": "",
                  "hasChildren": true,
                  "childActivityId": [
                    {
                      "activityId": 41896,
                      "activityCode": "0111001",
                      "description": "Graanteelt (m.u.v. rijst) : tarwe, rogge, gerst, haver, maïs, enz. (Mogelijk burgerlijke activiteit)",
                      "parentActivityId": "40424",
                      "parentActivityDescription": "Teelt van granen (m.u.v. rijst), peulgewassen en oliehoudende zaden (Mogelijk burgerlijke activiteit)",
                      "customAcertaActivity": false,
                      "isTradeActivity": true,
                      "requirementActivity": [],
                      "startDate": "2008-01-01",
                      "endDate": null,
                      "matchesQuery": "",
                      "version": "Versie 2008",
                      "versionMapping": [],
                      "comment": "",
                      "hasChildren": false,
                      "childActivityId": []
                    },
                    {
                      "activityId": 41897,
                      "activityCode": "0111002",
                      "description": "Teelt van oliehoudende zaden en van peulvruchten  : aardnoten, sojabonen, koolzaad, enz. (Mogelijk burgerlijke activiteit)",
                      "parentActivityId": "40424",
                      "parentActivityDescription": "Teelt van granen (m.u.v. rijst), peulgewassen en oliehoudende zaden (Mogelijk burgerlijke activiteit)",
                      "customAcertaActivity": false,
                      "isTradeActivity": true,
                      "requirementActivity": [],
                      "startDate": "2008-01-01",
                      "endDate": null,
                      "matchesQuery": "",
                      "version": "Versie 2008",
                      "versionMapping": [],
                      "comment": "",
                      "hasChildren": false,
                      "childActivityId": []
                    },
                    {
                      "activityId": 41898,
                      "activityCode": "0111003",
                      "description": "Teelt van drooggeoogste zaden van peulvruchten zoals erwten en bonen (Mogelijk burgerlijke activiteit)",
                      "parentActivityId": "40424",
                      "parentActivityDescription": "Teelt van granen (m.u.v. rijst), peulgewassen en oliehoudende zaden (Mogelijk burgerlijke activiteit)",
                      "customAcertaActivity": false,
                      "isTradeActivity": true,
                      "requirementActivity": [],
                      "startDate": "2008-01-01",
                      "endDate": null,
                      "matchesQuery": "",
                      "version": "Versie 2008",
                      "versionMapping": [],
                      "comment": "",
                      "hasChildren": false,
                      "childActivityId": []
                    },
                    {
                      "activityId": 41899,
                      "activityCode": "0111004",
                      "description": "Teelt van zaai- en plantgoed voor de akkerbouw (Mogelijk burgerlijke activiteit)",
                      "parentActivityId": "40424",
                      "parentActivityDescription": "Teelt van granen (m.u.v. rijst), peulgewassen en oliehoudende zaden (Mogelijk burgerlijke activiteit)",
                      "customAcertaActivity": false,
                      "isTradeActivity": true,
                      "requirementActivity": [],
                      "startDate": "2008-01-01",
                      "endDate": null,
                      "matchesQuery": "",
                      "version": "Versie 2008",
                      "versionMapping": [],
                      "comment": "",
                      "hasChildren": false,
                      "childActivityId": []
                    },
                    {
                      "activityId": 41900,
                      "activityCode": "0111005",
                      "description": "Teelt van overige akkerbouwgewassen, niet elders genoemd (Mogelijk burgerlijke activiteit)",
                      "parentActivityId": "40424",
                      "parentActivityDescription": "Teelt van granen (m.u.v. rijst), peulgewassen en oliehoudende zaden (Mogelijk burgerlijke activiteit)",
                      "customAcertaActivity": false,
                      "isTradeActivity": true,
                      "requirementActivity": [],
                      "startDate": "2008-01-01",
                      "endDate": null,
                      "matchesQuery": "",
                      "version": "Versie 2008",
                      "versionMapping": [],
                      "comment": "",
                      "hasChildren": false,
                      "childActivityId": []
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "activityId": 40100,
              "activityCode": "0112",
              "description": "Teelt van rijst",
              "parentActivityId": "39988",
              "parentActivityDescription": "Teelt van eenjarige gewassen",
              "customAcertaActivity": false,
              "isTradeActivity": false,
              "requirementActivity": [],
              "startDate": "2008-01-01",
              "endDate": null,
              "matchesQuery": "",
              "version": "Versie 2008",
              "versionMapping": [],
              "comment": "",
              "hasChildren": true,
              "childActivityId": [
                {
                  "activityId": 40425,
                  "activityCode": "01120",
                  "description": "Teelt van rijst (Mogelijk burgerlijke activiteit)",
                  "parentActivityId": "40100",
                  "parentActivityDescription": "Teelt van rijst",
                  "customAcertaActivity": false,
                  "isTradeActivity": true,
                  "requirementActivity": [],
                  "startDate": "2008-01-01",
                  "endDate": null,
                  "matchesQuery": "",
                  "version": "Versie 2008",
                  "versionMapping": [],
                  "comment": "",
                  "hasChildren": false,
                  "childActivityId": []
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "activityId": 40101,
              "activityCode": "0113",
              "description": "Teelt van groenten, meloenen en wortel- en knolgewassen",
              "parentActivityId": "39988",
              "parentActivityDescription": "Teelt van eenjarige gewassen",
              "customAcertaActivity": false,
              "isTradeActivity": false,
              "requirementActivity": [],
              "startDate": "2008-01-01",
              "endDate": null,
              "matchesQuery": "",
              "version": "Versie 2008",
              "versionMapping": [],
              "comment": "",
              "hasChildren": true,
              "childActivityId": [
                {
                  "activityId": 40426,
                  "activityCode": "01130",
                  "description": "Teelt van groenten, meloenen en wortel- en knolgewassen (Mogelijk burgerlijke activiteit)",
                  "parentActivityId": "40101",
                  "parentActivityDescription": "Teelt van groenten, meloenen en wortel- en knolgewassen",
                  "customAcertaActivity": false,
                  "isTradeActivity": true,
                  "requirementActivity": [],
                  "startDate": "2008-01-01",
                  "endDate": null,
                  "matchesQuery": "",
                  "version": "Versie 2008",
                  "versionMapping": [],
                  "comment": "",
                  "hasChildren": true,
                  "childActivityId": [
                    {
                      "activityId": 41901,
                      "activityCode": "0113001",
                      "description": "Teelt van paddestoelen en truffels (Mogelijk burgerlijke activiteit)",
                      "parentActivityId": "40426",
                      "parentActivityDescription": "Teelt van groenten, meloenen en wortel- en knolgewassen (Mogelijk burgerlijke activiteit)",
                      "customAcertaActivity": false,
                      "isTradeActivity": true,
                      "requirementActivity": [],
                      "startDate": "2008-01-01",
                      "endDate": null,
                      "matchesQuery": "",
                      "version": "Versie 2008",
                      "versionMapping": [],
                      "comment": "",
                      "hasChildren": false,
                      "childActivityId": []
                    },
                    {
                      "activityId": 41902,
                      "activityCode": "0113002",
                      "description": "Teelt van zaai- en plantgoed voor de groenteteelt (Mogelijk burgerlijke activiteit)",
                      "parentActivityId": "40426",
                      "parentActivityDescription": "Teelt van groenten, meloenen en wortel- en knolgewassen (Mogelijk burgerlijke activiteit)",
                      "customAcertaActivity": false,
                      "isTradeActivity": true,
                      "requirementActivity": [],
                      "startDate": "2008-01-01",
                      "endDate": null,
                      "matchesQuery": "",
                      "version": "Versie 2008",
                      "versionMapping": [],
                      "comment": "",
                      "hasChildren": false,
                      "childActivityId": []
                    },
                    {
                      "activityId": 41903,
                      "activityCode": "0113011",
                      "description": "Aardappelteelt (Mogelijk burgerlijke activiteit)",
                      "parentActivityId": "40426",
                      "parentActivityDescription": "Teelt van groenten, meloenen en wortel- en knolgewassen (Mogelijk burgerlijke activiteit)",
                      "customAcertaActivity": false,
                      "isTradeActivity": true,
                      "requirementActivity": [],
                      "startDate": "2008-01-01",
                      "endDate": null,
                      "matchesQuery": "",
                      "version": "Versie 2008",
                      "versionMapping": [],
                      "comment": "",
                      "hasChildren": false,
                      "childActivityId": []
                    },
                    {
                      "activityId": 41904,
                      "activityCode": "0113012",
                      "description": "Teelt van wortels en knollen met een hoog zetmeel- of inulinegehalte (Mogelijk burgerlijke activiteit)",
                      "parentActivityId": "40426",
                      "parentActivityDescription": "Teelt van groenten, meloenen en wortel- en knolgewassen (Mogelijk burgerlijke activiteit)",
                      "customAcertaActivity": false,
                      "isTradeActivity": true,
                      "requirementActivity": [],
                      "startDate": "2008-01-01",
                      "endDate": null,
                      "matchesQuery": "",
                      "version": "Versie 2008",
                      "versionMapping": [],
                      "comment": "",
                      "hasChildren": false,
                      "childActivityId": []
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "activityId": 40102,
              "activityCode": "0114",
              "description": "Teelt van suikerriet",
              "parentActivityId": "39988",
              "parentActivityDescription": "Teelt van eenjarige gewassen",
              "customAcertaActivity": false,
              "isTradeActivity": false,
              "requirementActivity": [],
              "startDate": "2008-01-01",
              "endDate": null,
              "matchesQuery": "",
              "version": "Versie 2008",
              "versionMapping": [],
              "comment": "",
              "hasChildren": true,
              "childActivityId": [
                {
                  "activityId": 40427,
                  "activityCode": "01140",
                  "description": "Teelt van suikerriet (Mogelijk burgerlijke activiteit)",
                  "parentActivityId": "40102",
                  "parentActivityDescription": "Teelt van suikerriet",
                  "customAcertaActivity": false,
                  "isTradeActivity": true,
                  "requirementActivity": [],
                  "startDate": "2008-01-01",
                  "endDate": null,
                  "matchesQuery": "",
                  "version": "Versie 2008",
                  "versionMapping": [],
                  "comment": "",
                  "hasChildren": false,
                  "childActivityId": []
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "activityId": 40103,
              "activityCode": "0115",
              "description": "Teelt van tabak",
              "parentActivityId": "39988",
              "parentActivityDescription": "Teelt van eenjarige gewassen",
              "customAcertaActivity": false,
              "isTradeActivity": false,
              "requirementActivity": [],
              "startDate": "2008-01-01",
              "endDate": null,
              "matchesQuery": "",
              "version": "Versie 2008",
              "versionMapping": [],
              "comment": "",
              "hasChildren": true,
              "childActivityId": [
                {
                  "activityId": 40428,
                  "activityCode": "01150",
                  "description": "Teelt van tabak (Mogelijk burgerlijke activiteit)",
                  "parentActivityId": "40103",
                  "parentActivityDescription": "Teelt van tabak",
                  "customAcertaActivity": false,
                  "isTradeActivity": true,
                  "requirementActivity": [],
                  "startDate": "2008-01-01",
                  "endDate": null,
                  "matchesQuery": "",
                  "version": "Versie 2008",
                  "versionMapping": [],
                  "comment": "",
                  "hasChildren": false,
                  "childActivityId": []
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "activityId": 40104,
              "activityCode": "0116",
              "description": "Teelt van vezelgewassen",
              "parentActivityId": "39988",
              "parentActivityDescription": "Teelt van eenjarige gewassen",
              "customAcertaActivity": false,
              "isTradeActivity": false,
              "requirementActivity": [],
              "startDate": "2008-01-01",
              "endDate": null,
              "matchesQuery": "",
              "version": "Versie 2008",
              "versionMapping": [],
              "comment": "",
              "hasChildren": true,
              "childActivityId": [
                {
                  "activityId": 40429,
                  "activityCode": "01160",
                  "description": "Teelt van vezelgewassen (Mogelijk burgerlijke activiteit)",
                  "parentActivityId": "40104",
                  "parentActivityDescription": "Teelt van vezelgewassen",
                  "customAcertaActivity": false,
                  "isTradeActivity": true,
                  "requirementActivity": [],
                  "startDate": "2008-01-01",
                  "endDate": null,
                  "matchesQuery": "",
                  "version": "Versie 2008",
                  "versionMapping": [],
                  "comment": "",
                  "hasChildren": false,
                  "childActivityId": []
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              "activityId": 40105,
              "activityCode": "0119",
              "description": "Teelt van andere eenjarige gewassen",
              "parentActivityId": "39988",
              "parentActivityDescription": "Teelt van eenjarige gewassen",
              "customAcertaActivity": false,
              "isTradeActivity": false,
              "requirementActivity": [],
              "startDate": "2008-01-01",
              "endDate": null,
              "matchesQuery": "",
              "version": "Versie 2008",
              "versionMapping": [],
              "comment": "",
              "hasChildren": true,
              "childActivityId": [
                {
                  "activityId": 40430,
                  "activityCode": "01191",
                  "description": "Teelt van bloemen (Mogelijk burgerlijke activiteit)",
                  "parentActivityId": "40105",
                  "parentActivityDescription": "Teelt van andere eenjarige gewassen",
                  "customAcertaActivity": false,
                  "isTradeActivity": true,
                  "requirementActivity": [],
                  "startDate": "2008-01-01",
                  "endDate": null,
                  "matchesQuery": "",
                  "version": "Versie 2008",
                  "versionMapping": [],
                  "comment": "",
                  "hasChildren": true,
                  "childActivityId": [
                    {
                      "activityId": 41905,
                      "activityCode": "0119101",
                      "description": "Teelt van bloemen en snijbloemen (Mogelijk burgerlijke activiteit)",
                      "parentActivityId": "40430",
                      "parentActivityDescription": "Teelt van bloemen (Mogelijk burgerlijke activiteit)",
                      "customAcertaActivity": false,
                      "isTradeActivity": true,
                      "requirementActivity": [],
                      "startDate": "2008-01-01",
                      "endDate": null,
                      "matchesQuery": "",
                      "version": "Versie 2008",
                      "versionMapping": [],
                      "comment": "",
                      "hasChildren": false,
                      "childActivityId": []
                    },
                    {
                      "activityId": 41906,
                      "activityCode": "0119102",
                      "description": "Vervaardiging van gedroogde bloemen",
                      "parentActivityId": "40430",
                      "parentActivityDescription": "Teelt van bloemen (Mogelijk burgerlijke activiteit)",
                      "customAcertaActivity": false,
                      "isTradeActivity": true,
                      "requirementActivity": {
                        "prerequisite": true
                      },
                      "startDate": "2008-01-01",
                      "endDate": null,
                      "matchesQuery": "",
                      "version": "Versie 2008",
                      "versionMapping": [],
                      "comment": "",
                      "hasChildren": false,
                      "childActivityId": []
                    },
                    {
                      "activityId": 41907,
                      "activityCode": "0119103",
                      "description": "Teelt van zaai- en plantgoed voor de bloementeelt (Mogelijk burgerlijke activiteit)",
                      "parentActivityId": "40430",
                      "parentActivityDescription": "Teelt van bloemen (Mogelijk burgerlijke activiteit)",
                      "customAcertaActivity": false,
                      "isTradeActivity": true,
                      "requirementActivity": [],
                      "startDate": "2008-01-01",
                      "endDate": null,
                      "matchesQuery": "",
                      "version": "Versie 2008",
                      "versionMapping": [],
                      "comment": "",
                      "hasChildren": false,
                      "childActivityId": []
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "activityId": 40431,
                  "activityCode": "01199",
                  "description": "Teelt van andere eenjarige gewassen, n.e.g. (Mogelijk burgerlijke activiteit)",
                  "parentActivityId": "40105",
                  "parentActivityDescription": "Teelt van andere eenjarige gewassen",
                  "customAcertaActivity": false,
                  "isTradeActivity": true,
                  "requirementActivity": [],
                  "startDate": "2008-01-01",
                  "endDate": null,
                  "matchesQuery": "",
                  "version": "Versie 2008",
                  "versionMapping": [],
                  "comment": "",
                  "hasChildren": false,
                  "childActivityId": []
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
           ] }],
  "page": {
    "pageSize": 20,
    "totalElements": 88,
    "currentPage": 0
  }
}
 
    }
  
    connectedCallback() {
      this.render();
    
    }
  

  
    render() {
      if (!this.data) {
        this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
          <p>Loading data...</p>
        `;
      } else {
        const tree = this.renderTree(this.data.result);
        this.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
          <ul>${tree}</ul>
        `;
        this.addEventListeners();
      }
    }
  
    renderTree(data) {
      let tree = '';
      for (const item of data) {
        tree += `<li>${item.description} (ID: ${item.activityId})`;
        if (item.childActivityId && item.childActivityId.length > 0) {
          const nestedChildren = this.renderTree(item.childActivityId);
          tree += `<ul>${nestedChildren}</ul>`;
        }
        tree += '</li>';
      }
      return tree;
      
    }
  
    addEventListeners() {
      const items = this.shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('li');
      for (const item of items) {
        const children = item.querySelector('ul');
        if (children) {
          children.style.display = 'none';

          item.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            
            event.stopPropagation();
                       
            children.style.display = children.style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
            
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  customElements.define('activity-index', ActivityIndex);
```

```html
<activity-index></activity-index>
```

Comment: Your code works indeed when I add the JSON hardcoded. When I fetch from api endpoint, it only shows the "parent" activities and output undefined (ID: undefined) for each child.

Comment: well, as the data is not reachable, it's impossible to say.. that would imply there are some items, but description and id are missing.. or something like that, if it still creates list items.. so try investigating data from that endpoint, does it really give the data in the same format etc.

Comment: It's odd that it doesn't give the problem when the json is hardcoded. The is the full json file: https://jsonblob.com/1123186087400062976

Comment: fixing click handler and hardcoding data makes it work, so you either have some different/cached data/file, or different code.. you could debug it further to isolate problem, for example add log to those items with undefined data, run on different domains/servers/clients.. etc.

Comment: I've found the issue. It seems that the old json was cached. By deleting the cache, the new json was loaded and everything seems to work. Thanks !